# Programmatically running a shell script in matlab

Tags: linux, bash, matlab, ssh

I am trying to open a terminal and run a script using matlab. The script will open an ssh connection. The matlab command is:

```
system(['lxterminal   -e "bash ' scriptName '" &'],'-echo');
```

When I execute the matlab command the script runs but fails fails to validate SSL credentials.

The script is running ssh through the python paramiko package.
The error arises from the cli.py module.

The problem is solved if I run

```
system(['lxterminal   -e "sudo bash ' scriptName '" &'],'-echo');
```

but then I have to enter the user password each time I execute the script.

If I open an lxterminal and run the same command:

```
bash scriptName
```

it works without the sudo.

I think it is related to some environmental variables / configuration which are not loaded in lxterminal before running the script, but cannot figure out it.

Using xterm instead of lxterminal has the same behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: Compare the output from `env` in your shell and in matlab.

Comment: Thanks, they look similar, the matlab one is larger. Both has the same user, logname and ssh-agent. The Matlab env  is larger (some more variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, AUTOMOUNT_MAP, XFILESEARCHPATH, ARCH). What should I look for? I use the Lubuntu distro. Finally if I run the script from the terminal that Matlab opened still i get ssh error.

Comment: The user and ssh-agent variables were the first ones I'd have looked at. If you spawn the terminal from matlab can you query the agent for your key correctly?

Comment: Hi, No. The same command when I run it from a CTR+ALT+T terminal works, but fails to validate SSL credentials when I run it from the terminal that matlab opens.

Comment: You can't query the ssh-agent from the matlab-spawned terminal? Are you sure it is running as the same user and using the same ssh-agent (same environment variables)? If the user and agent are the same what happens when you try to list the keys in the agent from the matlab-spawned terminal?

Comment: Hi, I query the ssh-agent from the matlab spawn terminal but it fails to validate SSL credentials. As posted earlier user and ssh-agent are the same in both working/not working terminals. I am puzzled for a day... I can cd to the ~/.ssh folder from the matlab terminal.

Comment: What does "fails to validate the credentials" mean? Do you see the correct key in the output from `ssh-add -l` while in the matlab-spawned terminal?

Comment: Hi, I added some more info in the problem description. The script is calling a python package which will then perform the ssh. Could it be that the python is not properly configured in the  shell spawned by matlab?

Comment: Can you answer the questions I've asked you? But if `sudo` works then it makes it seem like you aren't running `matlab` as the user you should be in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The fix, might be dirty, was to empty the LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the matlab environmental variables before calling  the system command using the following command in the matlab script

```
    setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH');
```

Probably the matlab LD_LIBRARY_PATH path is using obsolete libraries compared to the ones python needs.
A better approach might be to start removing one by one the paths until finding the one causing the problem.